# Arduino Serial - How to override all incoming buffer to get the latest string only

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, buffer

I'm using Serial.readString() to get the data sent from mobile over Bluetooth.
It works fine when I send data with a bit delay between sending times.
But when I send the data continuosly in a bit faster delay then the buffer will store all as a long string and then return that long string to Serial.readString().

Ex:
Sending

> 10
>
> 20
>
> 30
>
> 40

Receiving

> 10203040

I want to receive seperate values corresponding to the multiple sending times. Event it's really fast.

> 10
>
> 20
>
> 30
>
> 40

If that can not be achived, how can I get the latest value only (override all previous values in the buffer). In this case is 40

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arduino readString(); code runs slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42863973/arduino-readstring-code-runs-slow)

Comment: Why do you use readString ? With read you get the data byte by byte, therefore value by value.

Comment: I used readString as it's convenient and is a built-in solution. We don't need to write another loop to fetch single characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Command = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
```

Note that \n could be replaced with any character that indicates you want the readString to stop reading. For more info, check the [Arduino Docs](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/ReadStringUntil).

Comment: @HieuNguyen then please upvote it and accept it as the answer (by clicking on the check mark) so that others here who come to this link can easily solve it.

Comment: My reputation sore does not enough to vote up. But I marked your aswer as the best solution :)

Comment: Oh, that's fine then.